# Merge cpu cores for specific program

Tags: cpu, cpu-usage, multi-core, cpu-cores, threading

Minecraft is an old game that was coded to use only one core, which is bad for performance today,

so I was thinking if there is a way to like merge 2 cores for that specific program and make the program thinks it uses 1 core even tho it uses 2.

If that is somehow possible we can change the game for a lot of people.

Comment: What you want is not possible.

Comment: As Mokubai said, this is not possible.  Were it possible programmers would not have needed to come up with new paradigms to handle parallel processing - ie Minecraft would already be able to us it.  Versions of Minecraft >= 1.8 already uses multiple cores, although apparently its not very good at this.